Intuitive picture why Bose-Einstein condensation (BEC) does not occur in 2D and 1D
I know that the lack of Bose-Einstein condensation in 2D or 1D can be shown using the argument of the density of states and calculate the critical particle number or temperature for the condensation.
However, is there an intuitive physical picture without math why condensation does not occur in low dimensions?
Edit: This is a different question than here. I am not concerned about the calculations and density of states which are addressed there. I am rather concerned about phenomenological or "intuitive" explanation and understanding.

BECs are a very deep subject with a lot of math involved. I would be impressed by anyone able to provide such a picture.

This might answer your question: Possibility of Bose-Einstein condensation in low dimensions. I will also note that the wiki page for the Mermin Wagner theorem has a few relatively simple arguments for why this theorem is so.

I don't think this question has been answered. Draw the plot of density of states D(E) for 1, 2 and 3 dimensions. You'll see that the measure of states at zero energy goes to zero only for 3 and higher d. BEC works because of an energy entropy competition, at low temperature energy dominates so particles want to go to the low energy (ground) state. In 3d there's fewer low energy states, so the particles macroscopically condense into a single low energy state. In lower d, the particles have more available low energy states to increase entropy and does not condense into a single state.

To be more constructive: here is why the question should be reopened. OP has asked for intuition why BEC does not happen in lower dimensions. The confusion in the linked question is about the relation between BEC and Hohenberg-Mermin-Wagner theorem (which are similar but unrelated). OP here is not confused about that, they are able to do the calculation and show that there is no BEC for massive bosons in 1 and 2d. The relevant question here -- intuition behind this result -- is not addressed in the linked answer or comments.

You need to be more specific about what kind of intuition you're asking for. Simply asking for "intuition" without more details is too vague.

Is something along the lines of my first comment what you're looking for?

@NandagopalManoj it might be, yes

@VincentThacker any explanation which gives answer other than just consequences from mathematical calculations
